# uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, html, mysql, sql, jsp

JSP, SQL experts, I'm so grateful that I have got working solutions to all my previous posts as I'm a newbie to the above programming languages with just basic college knowledge. After getting the Java - SQL database data extraction working via command line (for basic understanding of JDBC) I have shifted back to 'JSP - SQL database access'.
This is my first example but when i try to execute it I get a XML error message, that **I guess** is about **Role Based Authentication**, **though I'm not sure**. Please I request your assistance preferably with basic steps of the solution.
**Below is the error message.**

```
HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be  resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

type Exception report

message The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:311)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:152)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1427)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

**Here is the JSP code:**

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*, java.util.*, java.sql.*" %>  
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*, javax.servlet.*" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>    
<html>
<head>
  <title>SELECT operation</title>
</head>
<body>

<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP"
     user="root" password="password"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Emp ID</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>

</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here are the file and class paths:**
**JSP page:** C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\jsp pages\RegName.jsp

**CLASSPATH:** C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar

**JAVA_HOME:** C:\glassfish3\jdk

**Path:** C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but it can help other!

As stated [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/the-absolute-uri-httpjava-sun-comjspjstlcore-cannot-be-resolved/), you can add to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

It worked for me!

Comment: Tu reponds comme ca sur des questions ou j'ai deja repondu?

Comment: Haha ! J'avais le même problème et ta solution ne fonctionnait pas. J'ai finit par trouver une autre façon et je l'ai partagé ici. C'est après que j'ai vu que c'était toi !

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `jstl` library to your classpath. Typically, it would go into `WEB-INF/lib`. You can get the binary jar [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2).

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis thanks it work but no data extracted from datase, I only receive a 4 column table with no data extracted why ?